# ACTION is unknown to this NavController cuando se presiona el boton back

Tags: android, mvvm, android-navigationview

Ando implementando Navigation component en mi proyecto en java.
Tengo 1 activity y varios fragments. Mi primer fragment (login) hace ciertas validaciones a la informacion del empleado y te redirecciona al fragment del menu.

```
loginViewModel.statusAsignacion.observe(this, loginResult -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "result = " + loginResult);
        binding.textViewLoginError.setText(loginResult);
        if (loginResult.equals(ASIGNACION_EXITOSA)) {
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_menuFragment);  //esta es la linea 92
        }
    });
```

La animacion se hace correctamente y entro sin problemas al menu, pero al presionar el boton back, obtengo el error `navigation destination xxxxxx:id/action_loginFragment_to_menuFragment is unknown to this NavController`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination xxxxx:id/action_loginFragment_to_menuFragment is unknown to this NavController
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:803)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:744)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:718)
    at com.wsircam.adn.mvvm.app.login.LoginFragment.lambda$onViewCreated$1(LoginFragment.java:92)
```

En mi grafo de navegación, la acción si esta definida.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="xxxx.app.login.LoginFragment"
    android:label="login_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_menuFragment"
        app:destination="@id/menuFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
    android:name="xxxx.app.menu.MenuFragment"
    android:label="menu_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/menu_fragment" />
```

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? a mi tmb me esta pasando lo mismo.

Comment: Si, se me olvido responderme a mi mismo jaja, si te interesa una respuesta mas completa la publico mas tarde, pero si quieres empezar a buscar, checa SingleLiveEvent

Comment: crees que eso ocurre por que se llamaba varias veces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que al usar mutableLiveData, la variable ya tiene un "estado" que en mi caso es "ASIGNACION_EXITOSA". Al cambiar de pantalla todo bien, pero al regresar, el "estado" de la variable sigue presente (ASIGNACION_EXITOSA), y el evento del observe en la MutableLiveData se activa, lo que provoca que se quiera mover nuevamente al fragment siguiente, pero como aun no se muestra el fragment original al presionar back, mi aplicacion fallaba. 
Otro escenario que lei, es que le dabas back y te enviaba directamente a la pantalla siguiente, pero ocurre por lo mismo.

La solucion fue utilizar SingleLiveEvent. Se puede leer del tema [aqui](https://medium.com/@abhishektiwari_51145/how-to-use-singleliveevent-in-mvvm-architecture-component-b7c04ed8705)

SingleLiveEvent en resumen y como su nombre lo dice, es un evento que solo se ejecuta una vez y que el evento se ejecute cuando realmente ocurre un cambio en el mutableLiveData. Eso hace que al regresar al fragment anterior al presionar back, el evento no se ejecute y por lo tanto no intenta cambiar de fragmento.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero validar para evitar navegar cuando te encuentras en el `menuFragment`,ya que si te encuentras en este Fragment no podrás navegar y obtendrás un `IllegalArgumentException` :

```
  if(NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).getCurrentDestination().getId() == NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).getGraph().getStartDestination()) {  
     NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_menuFragment);  

    }
```